# Creating multiple randomly named files on a desktop doesn't work with C++

Tags: c++, winapi

This program should create 10 randomly named files with unicode string names on a desktop but it only creates just 1. I tried using delete[] statements at the end of the `createfiles` function to deallocate the memory for output, file and desktop but it still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#include "shlobj_core.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

wchar_t* generateRandomUnicodeString(size_t len, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    wchar_t* ustr = new wchar_t[len + 1];
    size_t intervalLength = end - start + 1;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (auto i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ustr[i] = (rand() % intervalLength) + start;
    }
    ustr[len] = L'\0';
    return ustr;
}

void createfiles(int number)
{
    if (number == 0) {
        return;
    }
    wchar_t* output = generateRandomUnicodeString(5, 0x0400, 0x04FF);

    LPWSTR desktop;
    LPWSTR file;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, 0, &desktop);
    PathAllocCombine(desktop, output, 0, &file);

    std::wofstream ofs(file);
    ofs << "File Description";
    delete[] output;
    output = nullptr;
    delete[] file;
    file = nullptr;
    delete[] desktop;
    desktop = nullptr;

    createfiles(number - 1);
}
int main()
{
    createfiles(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Call `srand()` only once in the program, not every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function call `time(NULL)` is executed several times in the same second (which is probably happening in your case), then it will return the same value every time.

This means that you are seeding the random number generator with the same value every time you attempt to generate a random string. As a consequence, `rand` will generate the same sequence of random numbers every time. This means that you are generating the same random string every time you call the function `generateRandomUnicodeString`.

If you attempt to create the same filename 10 times, then only the first time will succeed and the remaining 9 times will fail, because that file already exists.

The simplest fix to your problem would therefore be to only call `srand` only once in your program, not every time `generateRandomUnicodeString` is called. This is best done at the start of the function `main`.

That way, you will only have the problem of generating the same sequence of random numbers if you call `main` more than once in the same second (i.e. if you start the program twice in the same second). It will no longer be a problem if you call `generateRandomUnicodeString` several times in the same second.